# kubectl get pods shows ErrImagePull

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Im trying to create a pod using my local docker image as follow.

1.First I run this command in terminal

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

2.I created a docker image as follow

```
sudo docker image build -t my-first-image:3.0.0 .
```

3.I created the pod.yml as shown below and I run this command

```
kubectl -f create pod.yml.
```

4.then i tried to run this command

```
kubectl get pods
```

but it shows following error

```
NAME                             READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
multiplication-b47499db9-phpb7   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          23h
my-first-pod                     0/1     ErrImagePull       0          7s
```

5.i get the pods logs

```
kubectl describe pod my-first-pod
```

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  99s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/my-first-pod to minikube
  Warning  Failed     41s (x3 over 94s)  kubelet, minikube  Failed to pull image "my-first-image:3.0.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for my-first-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
  Warning  Failed     41s (x3 over 94s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    12s (x4 over 93s)  kubelet, minikube  Back-off pulling image "my-first-image:3.0.0"
  Warning  Failed     12s (x4 over 93s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    0s (x4 over 98s)   kubelet, minikube  pulling image "my-first-image:3.0.0"
```

```
Dockerfile

    FROM node:carbon
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY . .
    CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

```
pods.yml

    kind: Pod
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
     name: my-first-pod
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: my-first-container
       image: my-first-image:3.0.0
```

```
index.js

    var http = require('http');
    var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
     response.statusCode = 200;
     response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
     response.end('Welcome to the Golden Guide to Kubernetes
    Application Development!');
    });
    server.listen(3000, function() {
     console.log('Server running on port 3000');
    });
```

Answer (score 13):

### Reason

This is because it can't download the docker image defined in your pod definition file. By default it downloads required images from [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/).

### Way 1

So after creating your `my-first-image:3.0.0` image you have to publish it at DockerHub. For that create an account at DockerHub and login from terminal using [login](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/) command

```
sudo docker login
```

After successful login, rebuild your docker image with your DockerHub username in tag and push it to DockerHub ([more details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_push/))

```
sudo docker image build -t YOUR_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME/my-first-image:3.0.0 .
sudo docker push YOUR_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME/my-first-image:3.0.0
```

Update your image in `pod.yml` as `YOUR_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME/my-first-image:3.0.0` and create your pods as before.

### Way 2

You can instruct to find required docker image from your local machine instead of downloading from DockerHub. To do so you have to add `imagePullPolicy: Never` in your `pod.yml` file under specific container description. Below is an example of your `pod.yml` file to show where to define image pull policy

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: my-first-pod
spec:
 containers:
 - name: my-first-container
   image: YOUR_DOCKERHUB_USERNAME/my-first-image:3.0.0
   imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the problem. But even with `imagePullPolicy: Never` in my pod.yaml, I'm still unable to reolve the exact error !! any more tips please

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using an image without uploading it .You will have to set the imagePullPolicy to Never, otherwise Kubernetes will try to download the image.

## Start minikube

minikube start

## Set docker env

eval $(minikube docker-env)

## Build image

docker build -t my-first-image:3.0.0 .

## Run in minikube

kubectl run my-first-container --image=my-first-image:3.0.0 --image-pull-policy=Never

## Check that it's running

kubectl get pods

Your pod spec should be like below

pods.yml

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: my-first-pod
spec:
 containers:
 - name: my-first-container
   image: my-first-image:3.0.0
   imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Comment: when i checked with kubectl get pods following error is 
shown my-first-pod                     0/1     ErrImageNeverPull   0          13s

Comment: did you set docker env as suggested 
eval $(minikube docker-env) ?

Comment: try removing the built image first . run eval $(minikube docker-env) before building the image. Then try running your pod again using the new image .

Answer (score 2):

You have build the image but you need to push to docker repository.

In case you are building docker image on kubernetes node, it can work but better to push to repository so docker will pull from central repo, as the number of nodes increases you cant control where pod will invoke and image will be unavailable.

```sh
docker push -t my-first-image:3.0.0
```

In case you have private docker repositiory, push to private repository and use full qualified image name.

Answer (score 1):

repository name is missing.

create an account in dockerHub.
then build and push the image to your repo in dockerhub

```
sudo docker image build -t niranga/my-first-image:3.0.0 .
sudo docker login
sudo docker push niranga/my-first-image:3.0.0
```

update the image name in pod.yaml file as niranga/my-first-image:3.0.0

it should work

Answer (score 0):

When you build image to local Minikube registry you might want to set `imagePullPolicy: Never` so that it will not try pulling the image from remote registry. 
The pod spec would look something like that:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: my-first-pod
spec:
 containers:
 - name: my-first-container
   image: my-first-image:3.0.0
   imagePullPolicy: Never
```

Comment: when i checked with kubectl get pods following error is shown `my-first-pod 0/1 ErrImageNeverPull'

Answer (score 0):

If you're using KiND, there is one extra step. I've taken the answer from here: https://iximiuz.com/en/posts/kubernetes-kind-load-docker-image/

Basically, you have to add it with:
`kind load docker-image image_name:latest`
then, make sure you add `imagePullPolicy: Never` to the yaml, as the previous answers mention. Additonally, make sure to tag a specific version of your image in the yaml, e.g. `image: image_name:latest`.